# Why is Friendly_ID gem using slug instead of primary key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-url, friendly-id

I'm getting an error from rails after installing Friendly_ID because the code is misinterpreting the input, and I don't know how to fix the problem. In order for the MVC framework to understand the url and route it accordingly, the url needs to fit the following pattern:

```
localhost:3000/posts/[:id]
```

Above, the `[id]` represents the primary key for any object found in the Post model class. The misinterpretation comes into effect when Friendly_ID changes the url to fit the following pattern:

```
localhost:3000/posts/[:slug]
```

The updated url is obviously easier to read by the user, but since my application expects to get an `[:id]`, it raises the following exception for the url "localhost:3000/posts/testing":

[image: Rails exception screenshot]

---

I had assumed that the Friendly_ID gem would either take care of the routing issue internally, perform some kind of `[:id]` lookup, or work its magic through some kind of url-masking. Since none of the above are true in this case, how to I resolve the issue, allowing the pretty-urls to deliver the same result as the original url pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finder overriding is disabled since gem version 5.0

Use `Post.friendly.find(params[:id])` or downgrade, or use finders addon, see [project github page](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id#friendlyid-features)

Comment: that works great! But is there an intuitive way to make rails accept either url pattern?

Comment: @elersong you can do that thing - friendly_id :foo, use: [:slugged, :finders] please refer to project github page

Comment: The github page doesn't mention where that code is supposed to go. Where am I supposed to put it?

Comment: @elersong  this code goes into your Post model. isn't it there already, just without the latter part?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. Github doesn't tell me where to put the `friendly_id :foo, use: [:slugged, :finders]` if I opt to use the `:finders` addon.

Comment: Put it at the top of `app/models/post.rb`. Right now you should have there `friendly_id :foo, use: :slugged`

Answer (score 0):

Add `config.use :finders` to your `config/initializers/friendly_id.rb`

Here's what mine looks like:

```
FriendlyId.defaults do |config|
  config.use :reserved

  config.reserved_words = %w(new edit index session login logout users admin
    stylesheets assets javascripts images)

  config.use :finders
end
```

Comment: I just checked my initializers directory, and I don't have that file there. Should it be?

Comment: It sets up default config. If you use friendly id only for one class, you don't need it. But if you use it for multiple classes, it's better to keep the config in one place.